# How to rename project in Android Studio `Reopen Project` list?

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, project, rename

Anyone knows how to rename this recently opened project **"gradle"** which I can find in my `File`->`Reopen Project` list?
[image: Recent project is called "gradle"]

Ubuntu 14.10
Android Studio 1.1 RC 1

Also affects open projects' list in `Window` menu:
[image: Android studio Window menu]

Comment: That did not help me yet. Will try to search solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I had to edit `.idea/.name` file. It looks like this:

[image: project's name file]

So I've added new project name into this `.name` file, and restarted Android Studio.